# git push/pull with ssh key

Tags: ssh, permissions, git, access-control, account-restrictions

- I have a 'git --bare' repo on a linux machine.
- I wish to allow another user from a different machine to push/pull to
  it.
- I have their ssh key.

Is there some way I can allow them to execute the command,

```
git clone ssh://user@server:/home/user/name.git
```

At the moment, I simply added their ssh key to my authorised keys... but that's not ideal. Searching around I only find suggestions for either moving to github or having a dedicated server with all the ssh keys for access (neither desirable).

Ideal would be if in the name.git directory I could execute something to add an ssh-key as an authorised pusher/puller,

```
git add --ssh <key> #not a real command
```

I'm on GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) with git 1.7.1.

---

**Update**: comments about [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) led me to find [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/299927/can-you-specify-git-shell-in-ssh-authorized-keys-to-restrict-access-to-only-git/444899#444899?newreg=d713cce0fa574964bcc25ccd71198ca5) which part solves my problem by using ssh 'authorized_key file formats' ([manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8?query=sshd)) to allow only [git-shell](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell) access. ssh-key-user now has access to only git folders, but I have not restricted their access to specific repo(s).

Comment: I think "gitolite" would be your friend. It uses ssh pubkey auth, has a fairly simle permission-system, and is easily configurable. In fact, you publish keys and premissions by editing the "gitolite-admin" repository, and pushing it to the server. https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite.git

Comment: *I simply added their ssh key to my authorised keys* Do the user connects through its own account?

Comment: @gerhardd.: Thank you for pointing me to gitolite! It looks very useful, but unfortunately I do not have root access, nor a 'fresh user id' that they mention as important. I still need to maintain my existing .ssh/authorized_keys file. I stumbled across git-shell too, but it seems similar to gitolite as I need to be able to add users to a machine (I think)... rather than just allowing me to provide git clone/push/pull access, for a particular ssh-key, to my git repo on my machine.

Comment: @A.L: I believe the user connects from a different machine and does not have an account on the server where my git repo is. My git repo is on a HPC cluster (so I have little admin control) and my colleague would access it from their work computer (which is another cluster, managed by someone else). I hope that answers it, I am not as clear in my head about Linux things as I should be.